# Не могу проверить в PHP выбрана ли кнопка Radio

Tags: php, html

В первые решил попробовать в создании сайтов себя, но увы тут я в тупике:

Пытаюсь отловить нажата ли radiobutton либо нет:

```
if (isset($_POST['addKeys']))
{
$MRF = "-1";
if($_POST["MRF_OBSHIY"] !="")
{$MRF = "0";}
if($_POST['MRF_YUG']!="")
{$MRF = "1";}
if($_POST['MRF_VOLGA']!="")
{$MRF = "2";}
if($_POST['MRF_CENTR']!="")
{$MRF = "3";}
if($_POST['MRF_DV']!="")
{$MRF = "4";}
if($_POST['MRF_SIBIR']!="")
{$MRF = "5";}
if($_POST['MRF_SZ']!="")
{$MRF = "6";}
if($_POST['MRF_URAL']!="")
{$MRF = "7";}

  $greet($_POST["Themess"],$_POST["Skeys"],$_POST["Sotvet"], $MRF);
}
?>
```

Где addKeys это кнопка для отправки данных, она отслеживается метод выполняется но где перечислены MRF_ не отлавливается, хотя radiobutton выбран.

Вот сама кнопка RadioButton:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input
      class="form-check-input"
      type="radio"
      name="MRF_OBSHIY"
      id="inlineRadio1"
      value="0"
    />
</form>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, уже 5 час сижу не могу найти информацию.

Comment: И да версия PHP 7.2

Answer (score 0):

А почему впринципе кнопка передается в POST запросе, если она никогда не передается? Соответственно isset($_POST['addKeys']) будет выдавать false и дальнейший код выполнен не будет. Необходимо производить проверку на поля, например:

```
if(isset($_POST["MRF_OBSHIY"])) {
    $general = trim(strip_tags($_POST['MRF_OBSHIY']));
    echo $general;
}
```

Если radio кнопка выбрана, то данный пример вернет ее value="", т.е. 0, если не выбрана, то $_POST['MRF_OBSHIY'] не будет существовать и на isset($_POST['MRF_OBSHIY']) будет возвращать false.

Comment: Наоборот кнопка отслеживается, она передаёт true

Comment: Проблемма в том что я не могу отследить выбрана ли radiobutton либо нет, а кнопка которая отвечает за отправку данных отслеживается, тобишь мне необходимо после нажатия на кнопку Отправить, проверить был ли выбран radiobutton либо нет, но при любых проверках , он ничего не возвращает.

Comment: Я не понимаю суть проблемы. Если кнопка выбрана, то она передается $_POST['radiobuttonname'] , а если не выбрана, то данного ключа в переменной $_POST не будет существовать. Для полной наглядности покажите весь код который выполняется. Либо так же в конце кода можете вывести все данные из $_POST переменной и посмотреть что возвращает форма. Для этого выполните print_r($_POST);

Comment: К сожалению вашим способом у меня не получилось, решение добавил выше.

Comment: Так вопрос был об отлавливании в PHP, а выше Вы привели пример в JS.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил.

Вот таким способом я получил информацию о том что выбран какой-либо радиобаттон, и получил его val();

```
if (!$('input[name="inlineRadioOptions"]').is(":checked")) {
      alert("Вы не выбрали МРФ.");
      return;
    }
    var text = $('input[name="inlineRadioOptions"]:checked').val();
```